# Getting Group with all permissions associated with it in Django

Tags: django, django-1.8

How to get a group with list of all associated permissions in Django?

I thought

```
group.permissions
```

gives error "auth.Permission.None"

But there are permissions assigned to the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use `group.permissions.all()`

[Documentation Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Group)

Comment: Solved. Thanks Paulo! Btw, when the documentation said group.permissions gives a list I got confused.

Comment: Yes, said group.permissions = [], this is to you define a list of a permissions, not to get they. :P